# How do I subset a dataset based on variable names using a loop?

Tags: r, loops

I have a health-related dataset which codes a variety of injuries in a binary way. I have successfully been able to create my output tables by writing the code for each injury variables in turn, but I know that a loop would make the very repetitive code much shorter. Each injury is mutually exclusive, that is a row where assault injury is 1 means asthma, copd, etc. are all 0.

Variable of interest: assault, asthma, copd, diabetes, falls, pneumonia

Other variables: indicator (this variable is just a value of 1, just so I don't have to write out the variables of interest each time in the code)

Values: 0 or 1

Here's an example of the code which I know works:

```
data_subset <- subset(master, assault == 1)
tbl <- as.data.frame(xtabs(~ age_cat + indicator, data = data_subset))
writeData(wb, "assault", tbl, startRow = 1, startCol = 1)
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "Assault.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

This gives me a nice little table which exported to an excel file named "Assault":

```
age_cat     indicator
00-04 years    6
05-14 years    4
15-25 years    16
25-34 years    26
35+ years      56
```

Pretty basic, so I figured I could use a loop through all the other variables in bulk by doing something like this:

```
varlist <- c('assault', 'asthma', 'copd', 'diabetes', 'falls', 'pneumonia')
for (i in varlist){
data_subset <- subset(master, i == 1)
tbl_i <- as.data.frame(xtabs(~ age_cat + indicator, data = data_subset))
writeData(wb, "i", tbl_i, startRow = 1, startCol = 1)
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "i.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)}
```

I'm running into an issue where "data_subset" always comes up as empty. I figured if it's running through each variable in turn (assault, asthma, copd..... pneumonia) I should end up with a "data_subset" dataframe which has only pneumonia observations. I tried only having "assault" in varlist just to try and replicate my output table above, no dice. I tried using

```
varlist <- list('assault', 'asthma', 'copd', 'diabetes', 'falls', 'pneumonia')
```

With no additional luck. At this point I'm not even worried about being able to write the final table to excel, I just need to figure out why "data_subset" is empty every time.

Comment: Try replacing `data_subset <- subset(master, i ==1)` with `subset(master, master[,i]==1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `subset`, use `[[`

```
varlist <- c('assault', 'asthma', 'copd', 'diabetes', 'falls', 'pneumonia')
for (i in varlist){
data_subset <- master[master[[i]] == 1,, drop = FALSE]
tbl_i <- as.data.frame(xtabs(~ age_cat + indicator, data = data_subset))
writeData(wb, "i", tbl_i, startRow = 1, startCol = 1)
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "i.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

---

For the `subset`, we may `eval`uate an expression

```
...
data_subset <- subset(master, eval(parse(text = paste(i,  '== 1'))))
...
```

As an example

```
> data(iris)
> sp <- "Species"
> subset(iris, sp == 'setosa')
[1] Sepal.Length Sepal.Width  Petal.Length Petal.Width  Species     
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> subset(iris, eval(parse(text = paste(sp, '== "setosa"')))) |> head(2)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, your method did the trick. if anyone else needs to export to excel using a similar method make sure to add: "wb<-createWorkbook() addWorksheet(wb, i) and modify the lines writeData(wb, i, tbl_i, startRow = 1, startCol = 1) and saveWorkbook(wb, file = paste0(i ,".xlsx", overwrite = TRUE). Mind the quotation marks!